# Local area network virtualhost apache

Tags: apache, dns, localhost, ip, reverse-proxy

I have an `Apache 2.4` http server as a reverse proxy server. In all the tutorials it is stated that I need to use `VirtualHost` and specify IP address or host name. I am trying to make it working on every PC I run the server.

My question is following:

> How to make `SSL/HTTPS` connection working if I don't know the IP address
>   which will be used? Maybe it will be even a DHCP-provided IP

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Comment: If it says "specify IP address **or** host name", that would mean that you don't have to know the ip address?

Comment: @DusanBajic but I have no DNS records as well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This question would be better asked over on https://serverfault.com/, they will have the expertise you need.

Comment: @mognurodro What will user type in browser address bar in order to access the website?

Comment: @DusanBajic an IP address which will be assigned using DHCP or a static one, for example, 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.100.50 or 10.20.30.1

Comment: You can use `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Also, if you don't specify `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` (or if none is matched), the first virtual host will be used.